# JAXB: Unmarshalling xhtml fragments

Tags: jaxb

I have a third-party schema XSD that, besides elements from its own namespace, allows the inclusion of formatted text fragments, in XHTML. Say (a trimmed down sample) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/myns" 
xmlns:myns="http://www.example.org/myns" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xsd:element name="body">
<xsd:complexType >
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="expression" type="xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name="documentation" type="myns:formattedText" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>


<xsd:complexType name="formattedText">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" processContents="lax"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


</xsd:schema>
```

I generated my Java clases using JAXB (Sun) (`xfc myschema.xsd`) and the unmarshalling works excepts for the formattedText node, its `getAny()` method returns null.

I'm not at all interested in getting the xhtml DOM in Java, I just want the raw text (CDATA). I guess that, if I were allowed to modify the schema, replacing in the above the line :

```
  <xsd:element name="documentation" type="xsd:string" />
```

would be enough, but I'd prefer other way, if possible. I know very little about JAXB. Any tips?

Update: I updated the schema sample, so it can be tested verbatim. I'd wish, for that schema and for the following sample xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
       xmlns="http://www.example.org/myns"         
       xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/myns">

   <expression>hi</expression>
   <documentation>  
         Hello <b>world</b>
   </documentation>

</body>
```

to get a Body class that returns in its body.getDocumentation().getAny() method, the raw string `Hello <b>world</b>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation and specify a `DomHanlder` to convert that section of XML to a `String` in your domain model.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make it work. I updated the question. If I annotate `FormattedText` class with `@XmlAnyElement(FormattedTexHandler.class)`, the handler sees the inside element (starting with '<b...>world</b>') but misses the outer text